# Can you use batches of SQL in mySQL the way you can with SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

With SQL Server, I can send

```
SELECT * FROM FOO
SELECT * FROM BAR
```

to the server and get back the results of both, all in one trip.

Can I do that with mySQL also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speak about the mysqli-extension for PHP, but I guess the same will be possible with most mysql-libraries. In PHP, you can send multiple queries, like

```
SELECT * FROM foo; SELECT * FROM bar;
```

with `mysqli_multi_query()` and iterate through the result-sets with `mysqli_next_result()`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the queries have the same number of columns you can do a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) on the two queries, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM foo 
UNION
SELECT * FROM bar
```

Comment: Corey Tragers syntax, in SQL Server, would return two recordsets - quite probably with different columns in each - so in the application you could first do a NextRecord loop to process the first recordset, and then a NextRecordSet to get to the second.